# mat3x4 in webGL shaders

Tags: javascript, html5, glsl, webgl

I am porting the [IQM](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm/blob/master/demo/gpu-demo.cpp) bone animation format to Javascript and have run into a problem...

The vertex shader is failing to compile and the only error message I get out is `'mat3x4' : syntax error` on the first occurance of `mat3x4` in the file.  Its the very data-type name itself that is unsupported, it seems.

This happens on all machines I have access to for testing, which have a variety of Intel and ATI cards and run Linux with Firefox.  (Chrome is not available.)

If I change all `mat3x4` to, say, `mat3` then my shader compiles fine.

1. does webGL support `mat3x4`?  (I can find nothing via Google)
2. how can I work around this?  How can I package the bones into `mat4`, for example, and keep the code working correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- Unfortunately no, the [WebGL standard](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#4.3) references the [GLSL ES 1.0 standard](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf), which only has square matrices (section 4.1.6).

2- A `mat3x4` holds 12 floats, so you may need to pass the information as a `mat4` to the shader anyway (`mat3` only holds 9). In that case you will need to use 4×4 matrices in the client code, too, and fill the last column with the values `[0 0 0 1]`.

This will use 30% more uniform space, unfortunately, but then some parts of the shader can be simplified:

```
 vec4 mpos = vec4(gl_Vertex * m, gl_Vertex.w);
```

simply becomes:

```
vec4 mpos = gl_Vertex * m;
```

2bis- One other solution is to send the array of `Matrix3x4` as an array of `Vec4` and rebuild the matrix in the shader:

```
uniform vec4 bonemats[240];

[...]

vec4 c1 = bonemats[3*int(vbones.x)]   * vweights.x;
vec4 c2 = bonemats[3*int(vbones.x)+1] * vweights.x;
vec4 c3 = bonemats[3*int(vbones.x)+2] * vweights.x;
c1 += bonemats[3*int(vbones.y)]   * vweights.y;
c2 += bonemats[3*int(vbones.y)+1] * vweights.y;
c3 += bonemats[3*int(vbones.y)+2] * vweights.y;

[...]

m = mat4(c1, c2, c3, vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));

[...]

vec4 mpos = gl_Vertex * m;
```

If you do that, the client code needs not be modified if your `Matrix3x4` array is stored [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).